# why are scalar fields lorentz invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

In a QFT book i study, it says that all scalar fields are Lorentz invariant because every scalar quantity does stay same in whichever frame you are looking. For example if you label with the temperature of each point on a piece of paper. the temperature stays same even if you rotate or move it, only the labels change. That's why scalar scalar fields are Lorentz invariant.

However this definition of in-variance sounds strange to me. Let me explain this with an example. Let we have two pieces of paper, one of them has a temperature of 150k on every point exept there is a red filled circle on it which is 200K of temperature.

The other of them is also 150k on everywhere but there is random drawing on it, which is 200k of temperature.

Now, for me the first one is rotationally symmetric around the traverse perpendicular axis passing through the center of the circle.

but the second one does not have have any symmetry.

however, according to previous definition of in-variance both of them are lorenzt invariant because the temperature does not depend only the labeling depends and how we label does not tell anything about the nature( but it tells something about the nature as in my example).

Thus I am not sure if this kind of definition of rotations and lorentz transformations compile with the definitions we did in quantum mechanics.

In qm a state ket rotates as$$|\alpha\rangle_R=\mathcal{D}(R)|\alpha\rangle$$ thus the wavefunction rotates as
$$\langle x|\alpha\rangle_R=\langle x|\mathcal{D}(R)|\alpha\rangle=\langle R^{-1}x|\alpha\rangle$$ 
How ever in this book it says that scalar fields are lorentz invariant and they just don't change, which contradicts with the derivation i just made.
[image: This]is the section of the book I am talking about.

Comment: You're imagining an active transformation. The text is talking about a passive transformation, a relabeling of the points.

Comment: In the QM example, $_{R}\langle x|=\langle x|\mathcal{D}^\dagger(R)$. Since $\mathcal{D}$ is unitary, $_{R}\langle x|\alpha\rangle_R=\langle x|\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: @J.G.          I am not sure if the base kets also rotates. I mean it is like Schrodinger picture in SP time evolution rotates the state kets but not base kets that is why in SP operators stays stationary.I think the rotation is same as SP if base kets also were rotated than both operators and state ket would rotate, which would give unaffected mean values, which is not true.

Comment: @physshyp Operators may update, but only in a way that preserves the identity operator, so we do need to update the bras to make things work.

Comment: @J.G.          What you did is definitely not correct, it should hit the state ket, not the base ket.  You can check the book of Sakurai he also only hits the state ket when he is rotating a system.

Comment: @physshyp If by base ket you mean bra, I suspect the difference with Sakurai is a matter of conventions.

Comment: @J.G.          https://imgur.com/a/duA2y

Comment: @knzhou        In that case the wave function would still change. active vs passive is the difference between whether your transformation hits the basis or the states. It is really the difference between, Heisenberg and Schrodinger picture.

Comment: Temperature is a scalar field because it is the heat flow between potentials. The mean values from global measurements is the average difference in flux density, as points , which gives the exact constant heat flow through the system. With 1360.8W/m^2 going into a spherical volume, we get TSI/(4/3)=4/3*8g^2.
4g^2=T^4 average

Comment: Heat and work, dU(TSI)=4W(g^2)+4Q(244.5W/m^2, T^4_eff)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to combine this with a greenhouse effect?''''

Comment: Maybe co2 is the controll-knob on gravity;)